# Find class from web in python 3.6 not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Please let me know how to find the class from HTML Code from the URL: https://knoema.com/MIG_UNEMP_GENDER_2015

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://knoema.com/MIG_UNEMP_GENDER_2015')
soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')
soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'metadata-block validate'})
```

Result giving blank.

Comment: Because the link you gave doesn't have any class having name `'metadata-block validate'`

Comment: @ Rahul thanks for reply, there is class, if you select inspect element on link (http://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=MIG_NUP_RATES_GENDER) given after Original Data, please check

Comment: There is not such class in the both url you submitted so far.

Comment: What is the value you want to extract?

Comment: Want to extract link given after Original Data i.e http://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=MIG_NUP_RATES_GENDER

Comment: Can you locate the area you are targeting? I can neither find any class named `metadata-block validate` nor get you as you mention `link given after original data`? A photo would help.

Comment: @Khanh Nguyen, I can not attach any image here.

Comment: @faithon: how about uploading to a host?

Comment: `https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipPpDDOD7Esnc6GiC8pV5hKmQTWGti9IYei_Xbkg`. Here's a look at what I got from the website, the tags work fine though some tweaks are needed to get them organized.

Comment: They allow you to use the developer API, I am playing with it to see if it works out. Stuck now :/

Comment: @Khanh Nguyen, thanks for effort. Actually class was hidden for external user, I had credentials so that I can see Original Data followed by link. I will check again come back.